# How to free double pointer array in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function to deallocate/free a double pointer in C. I have a struct that has an allocated char, and a double pointer to another struct I have. I need to create a function free of that memory. The structs I have:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    int age;
    int height;
} student;

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    char *location; // allocated
    double area;
    int population;
    student **students; // fully allocated, NOT a reference array
} school;
```

I need to dispose the school function, I do have a function already but I'm not sure it's right

```
void dispose_school(school *r)
{

    free(r->name);
    free(r->location);
    free(r->students[i]);
    free(r);
}
```

If someone can shine some light, thank you!

Comment: No it is not right. Because the `dispose_school` uses an undefined variable `i`. And even if `i` is defined it still looks incorrect as that would only free one element in the whole array. Can you please provide a complete [mre]. Specifically we need to see how you are allocating `students` to be able to advise on how to free it.

Comment: Because it's [probably] small enough, please _edit_ your question and post your _entire_ program in a _single_ code block (easier for _you_ and _us_). We need to see how you're allocating/filling `students` in the `school` struct and how you're allocating a given `student` struct.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate through all the elements of `students`, free them. And then after your loop completes, free `students` as well. See this code-

```c
for(int i = 0;i < r->population;i++) {
    free(r->students[i]->name); // do this if your students[i]->name is dynamically allocated
    free(r->students[i]);
}

free(r->students);
```

Comment: The OP would also need to `free( r->students[i]->name )`  (the `student.name`) ... assuming it's actually allocated.

Comment: Well, yeah good catch. I actually forgot that `student` was a `struct`, not simply a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing the double pointer is straightforward. You have the **pointers** you allocate to hold each `student`, you have the struct you allocate to hold each students values (`name`, `age`, `height`), and finally you have the `name` you allocated storage for to hold the student's name. This specifies the order in which you would have needed to allocate the memory.

To `free()` a complex set of allocations, you simply take the order **in reverse**. Here you have some number of students (the `population`), so you would loop `school->population` times freeing:

- the block of memory allocated to hold the students `name`;
- the block of memory for the student struct holding the name, age and height; and finally

After the loop completes, then you free all of the pointers `students`.

That will free all the memory you have allocated for `students`, but you are not done. You will have also allocated storage for the school `name`, `location` and perhaps the school struct itself (unless you declared the base school struct with *automatic-storage-duration*).

Presuming you have allocated for the school struct and the rest of the pointers, you can write a free function that takes a pointer to the school and free all memory with something similar to the following (assuming you have used `school->population` as the student counter):

```c
void destroy_school (school *s)
{
  /* loop over each student and free storage for (1) name and (2) struct */
  while (s->population--) {
    free (s->students[s->population]->name);
    free (s->students[s->population]);
  }
  
  /* free storage for student pointers */
  free (s->students);
  
  /* free school name, location and school struct */
  free (s->name);
  free (s->location);
  free (s);               /* remove if s has automatic-storage-duration */
}
```

**A Short Example**

Putting the pieces together to allocate and `free()` all the needed information, you can write a short program to do so. Splitting the code into functions to `create_school()`, `add_student()`, `print_school()` and `destroy_school()` keeps the logic straight. Using the `population` as your student counter, you could do something similar to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    int age;
    int height;
} student;

typedef struct {
    char *name; // allocated
    char *location; // allocated
    double area;
    int population;
    student **students; // fully allocated, NOT a reference array
} school;

school *create_school (const char *name, const char *loc, double area)
{
  school *s = NULL;                   /* create school ptr init NULL */
  size_t len = strlen (name);         /* get lenght of name parameter */
  
  if (!(s = malloc (sizeof *s))) {    /* allocate/VALIDATE struct school */
    perror ("malloc-s");              /* handle error on allocation fail */
    return NULL;                      /* return failure */
  }
  
  if (!(s->name = malloc (len + 1))) {  /* allocate/VALIDATE for name */
    perror ("malloc-s.name");           /* handle error on allocation fail */
    free (s);                           /* clean up previous allocations */
    return NULL;
  }
  memcpy (s->name, name, len + 1);      /* copy name to s->name */
  
  len = strlen (loc);
  
  if (!(s->location = malloc (len + 1))) {  /* allocate/VALIDATE for loc */
    perror ("malloc-s.loc");                /* handle error */
    free (s->name);                         /* clean up prior allocations */
    free (s);
    return NULL;
  }
  memcpy (s->location, loc, len + 1);   /* copy location to school */
  
  s->area = area;                       /* set area and pop */
  s->population = 0;
  
  s->students = NULL;                   /* init students ptr NULL */
  
  return s;                             /* return allocated school struct */
}

int add_student (school *s, const char *name, int age, int height)
{
  size_t len = strlen (name);         /* length of name */
  void *tmp;
  
  /* reallocate/VALIDATE pointer for next student
   * ALWAYS realloc() using a temporary pointer so if realloc() fails
   * you don't overwrite your original pointer with NULL creating a 
   * memory leak.
   */
  if (!(tmp = realloc (s->students, (s->population + 1) * 
                                      sizeof *s->students))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc student: %d\n", s->population);
    return 0;   
  }
  s->students = tmp;                  /* assign realloc'ed block to students */
  
  /* allocate/VALIDATE storage for struct student */
  if (!(s->students[s->population] = malloc (sizeof **s->students))) {
    perror ("malloc-s->students[s->population");
    return 0;
  }
  
  /* allocate/VALIDATE storage for student name */
  if (!(s->students[s->population]->name = malloc (len + 1))) {
    perror ("malloc-s->students[population]->name");
    return 0;
  } /* copy name to allocated space */
  memcpy (s->students[s->population]->name, name, len + 1);
  
  s->students[s->population]->age = age;         /* assign age and height */
  s->students[s->population]->height = height;
  s->population += 1;                            /* increment pop count */
  
  return 1;         /* return success */
}

void print_school (school *s)
{
  printf ("\nSchool     : %s\n"
          "Location   : %s\n"
          "Area       : %.2f\n"
          "N-Students : %d\n\n", 
          s->name, s->location, s->area, s->population);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < s->population; i++) {
    printf ("  %02d  %-16s  %4d  %4d\n", 
            i,
            s->students[i]->name, 
            s->students[i]->age, 
            s->students[i]->height);
  }
}

void destroy_school (school *s)
{
  /* loop over each student and free storage for (1) name and (2) struct */
  while (s->population--) {
    free (s->students[s->population]->name);
    free (s->students[s->population]);
  }
  
  /* free storage for student pointers */
  free (s->students);
  
  /* free school name, location and school struct */
  free (s->name);
  free (s->location);
  free (s);
}

int main (void) {
  
  /* allocate/initialize struct school, population == 0, students == NULL */
  school *RidgeMontHigh = create_school ("Ridgemont High", 
                                          "Hollywood, CA", 2357.8);
  
  if (!RidgeMontHigh) {   /* validate creation of school */
    return 1;
  }
  
  /* add students to school (can validate each, but population will do) */
  add_student (RidgeMontHigh, "Mickey Mouse", 103, 48);
  add_student (RidgeMontHigh, "Minnie Mouse",  99, 44);
  add_student (RidgeMontHigh, "Pluto (the dog)", 97, 47);
  add_student (RidgeMontHigh, "Daffy Duck", 102, 46);
  
  if (RidgeMontHigh->population == 0) {   /* validate non-zero student pop */
    return 1;
  }
  
  print_school (RidgeMontHigh);       /* print school followed by students */
  destroy_school (RidgeMontHigh);     /* free all memory involved */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compiling and running the code will produce the following:

```
./bin/schoolpop

School     : Ridgemont High
Location   : Hollywood, CA
Area       : 2357.80
N-Students : 4

  00  Mickey Mouse       103    48
  01  Minnie Mouse        99    44
  02  Pluto (the dog)     97    47
  03  Daffy Duck         102    46
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/schoolpop
==18986== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18986== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18986== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18986== Command: ./bin/schoolpop
==18986==

School     : Ridgemont High
Location   : Hollywood, CA
Area       : 2357.80
N-Students : 4

  00  Mickey Mouse       103    48
  01  Minnie Mouse        99    44
  02  Pluto (the dog)     97    47
  03  Daffy Duck         102    46
==18986==
==18986== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18986==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18986==   total heap usage: 16 allocs, 16 frees, 1,290 bytes allocated
==18986==
==18986== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18986==
==18986== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18986== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.